# parley.js css not work in dynamic load form generate by ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, parsley.js

I am load a dynamic form in fancybox with jquery-ajax, my form is made in a asp.net mvc4  partialview, in partial view i have this code

and the form, the validation is well, but css error, succes etc not working

when i create a form in "normal" view, everithing work. :(

Please help,

Thanks

```
<form id="parsleyForm">

<input type="text" required />

<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<script>
  $('#parsleyForm').parsley()
</script>
```

Comment: Care to provide a fiddle?

Comment: Hi @Mar, thanks for your request, is something like this, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/orinthe/ZJ6Dz/, in the example is only a field, but in my proyect is a form. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upgrade your version of Parsley. Taking your fiddle and changing from `2.0.0-rc2` to `2.1.0-rc2` fixes the issue.